# Sorting div class with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I created jQuery plugin to sort class with `class="apple"` and `class="tree"` but how do I create a sort with displaying all of the above `class="apple"` ?

```
<ul>
  <li class="apple">APPLE</li>
  <li class="tree">TREE</li>
  <li class="all">ALL</li>
</ul>

<div>
  <div class="apple">APPLE</div>
  <div class="tree">TREE</div>
  <div class="apple">APPLE</div>
  <div class="tree">TREE</div>
  <div class="apple">APPLE</div>
  <div class="tree">TREE</div>
</div>

<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("ul li").click(function() {
  visibleClasses = $(this).attr("class").split(" ");
  $("div div").hide(); // or slideUp / fadeOut
  for(i in visibleClasses) {
    $("div div."+visibleClasses[i]).fadeIn(500); // or slideDown / show
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Probably you want to "filter" and not to "sort". And I can't understand your question. What exactly doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use class `apple tree` instead of using `all`

```
<li class="apple tree">ALL</li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mAQwg/

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted seems to work, with the exception of the 'all' option. I've created a jsFiddle with a quick and dirty 'all' function at:

http://jsfiddle.net/fpA7Z/2/